# How to add custom error page when there is no internet connection available

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

how can add my own error page replacing default error page "webpage not available" when there no internet connection available. like below image 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgS7o.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i got solution by adding below code

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient()
  {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView webview, int i, String s, String s1)
  {
      mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
  }
   });
```

put your own html error page in assets folder

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply Broadcast receiver and register Network Connection event when event rising according to there status redirect your page.

Comment: check this link, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html  and http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/